# What is this "drive circuit" for CCD sensor referenced to?

Tags: voltage, analog, signal, datasheet, ccd

I had a look at the [TCD1304DG CCD sensor](http://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=13709&prodName=TCD1304DG) which I consider using in a project. The datasheet is pretty lucid, but I couldn't figure out what the following diagram is supposed to say:

[image]
[image]

Is this just a common way of illustrating an analog signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that Vos is referenced to the ground pin which usually doesn't need to be defined. The Vdmk signal is not referenced to ground, it's referenced to the OS signal (which I think is also Vos). This could also mean that both are a sum of some kind. Either way the Vos/OS signal goes from 1.5 to 3.5V